# Remove Email Footer while sending an email to contact

Tags: community, email, salesforce1-app, singleemailmessage

While sending an email to a contact a footer is getting included.
I have to remove this footer
I went through "Organization-Wide Email Footers" and have set one as a default footer.

But my footer is displayed after the default salesforce footer.

Can I remove this footer? If yes how?
[image]

=====================================
Email Footer ==========================

[image]

Comment: goto Email Administration --> Email Footers --> and deactived the footer

Comment: I did the same but I am getting the same footer as i attached in the above image

Answer (score 4):

This question is very old, but like me, other people may have it even today.  All my google searching hasn’t turned up an answer.  So I will share what I have found.

The text:

---

Powered by Salesforce
http://www.salesforce.com/

It not part of a footer.  Adding a footer will place it above this text.

This text is a tag line that can be removed in the paid editions, but not from a playground.  You will see a notice saying so under “My Email Settings”, under user settings > email.

Comment: Thanks, this saved me from more googling and wrapping my head around how to remove this.